# Access Slide link through AppScripts/Google API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

If you copy and paste a slide from one presentation to another manually, you are given the option to "link" the two.

I haven't found a way to access this link through AppScripts or the REST API, but wanted to verify.

Questions that I have seen in regards to this are about sheets being linked in slides.  There are methods for that but haven't seen any for my use case.

Below, is a reference photo of what I'm looking to access (follow black arrow)

[Reference of the link image I'm looking to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgQQg.png)

Comment: could you kindly explain what you mean by "linking" the slides. Kindly elaborate on what you are trying to achieve by doing so.

Comment: By linking I mean having a slide in deck A which would act as Master then the having the same slide be in deck B.  In deck B you can update the slide to have the same contents as deck A if changes to A are made.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that there are no methods for retrieving the link yet. So as a workaround, how about updating the "B" by running a script when the "A" is changed? If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for verifying.  That's an option, but we wanted to stick with as much native functionality as possible.  Maybe I'll float it at standup.

Comment: @Max Rashes I'm sorry for my late reply. I think that the workaround can be achieved by the native functions for Slides service.